# IntelliJ & Emmet: How to reference live templates inside of other live templates

Tags: intellij-idea, emmet, live-templates

With Emmet, I can create a snippets.json file with custom Emmet abbreviations.  For example:

```
"custom:icon": "link:favicon[href=\"img/favicon.ico\"]"
```

When I expand

```
custom:icon
```

It first reads the custom entry:

```
link:favicon[href=\"img/custom-favicon.ico\"]
```

Which, due to the 'link:' reference, will then expand into:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="custom-favicon.ico" />
```

However, when I add this custom abbreviation into IntelliJ's Live Templates and use it, it stops at the custom entry and doesn't expand the link tag per Emmet's rules.  As a result, it displays:

```
link:favicon[href=\"img/custom-favicon.ico\"]
```

How do I get it to keep expanding the Emmet tags inside the custom Live Template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Nested" live templates are not supported; please follow [IDEABKL-6832](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6832) for updates